# Hooking up Raid0 drives to Dell XPS

Tags: hard-drive, raid, dell-xps

I recently dug up a pare of WD Raptor 74GB hard drives that I had once upon a time in an older custom built computer they were RAID0. I now have a Dell Studio XPS 8000 desktop that I'd like to see whats still on these oldish drives.

Problem is that my dell desktop only has SATA connectors and power is not ATX. (Drives are both ATX power and IDE.

Whats the cheapest why to set these up so that I can boot these as a RAID0 slave to my current desktop and see whats still on them?

Comment: You realize that RAID0 is implemented with different defaults on many RAID controllers.  Even if you get them physically connected, you can't just set them up in a RAID0 in your BIOS and have things magically work.  It is likely that the simple act of trying to configure them as a RAID0 will wipe out the data.  If you don't have access to the original RAID controller, then you probably should treat these drives as if they are unrecoverable.

Comment: As for connecting them, go to your favorite store, and buy two USB-to-IDE adapters.

Comment: Hrm didn't realize that. This is the mobo that I was using with these drives http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=DH800 - I don't have it anymore though.